# How I use Python to change the text and push the submit button?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to use code to change data.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<tr>
  <td align="right"><b>溫冰過熱</b></td>
  <td><input name="textfield[6]" type="text" value="52" size="7" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I want to change the "value" 52 to others. But I have no idea.

Finally, push the submit button to save the change.

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
```

I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('User', 'Password'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
toohot = soup.find_all(attrs={'name':'textfield[6]'})
toohot.value = "45"
```

Here is the picture about the website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnlbc.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: The submit `button` is part of your web browser. Do you want to automate the browser? You could use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Or do you just want to post data to a url? You can just use [**`requests.post`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for that.

Comment: @Peter Wood but I consider that the requests.post is for the json? If I want to use that I have to use what key? textfield[6] and value?

Comment: `json` is unrelated